# Redirect all subdomain to main domain except one selected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

If I want to redirect all subdomains to a main domain, except one subdomain that I need redirect to a subfolder. Is there any way?

1. Redirect selected subdomain to subfolder
2. Redirect all subdomains to main domain

This is my Apache configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mySubdomain\.domain\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/mySubdomain  [L,R]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: So did you try the above?

Comment: Do you have all subdomains pointing to the server too? As in your Dns setup.

Comment: Yes, DNS is pointing correctly on server.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule is correct to serve a particular subdomain from a directory. For the second rule just add 1 AND condition that if the current request is not for domain.com AND not for mySubdomain.domain.com then redirect request to domain.com as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mySubdomain\.domain\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/mySubdomain/$1  [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mySubdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```